# Provider from react-redux Doesn't Work for me

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

[This is the code in index file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MvgK.png)

[the packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia7zh.png)

i try to copy past a valid code but it doesnt work
Please if anyone has the same probléme can help me

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific on what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (1) What exactly is the problem or issue you face? Simply saying "it's not working" isn't very helpful for anyone. (2) We can't very well help resolve issues with code we can't see. Please do edit your post to include a relevant [mcve] of the code you have an issue working with and using.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps... it's working example which i showed you .
Just you remove persist config instead use thunk which you are using i guess.

```js
index.js 
import {store }  from './Redux/Store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store} ><App/></Provider>
);

and in Store.js

import { legacy_createStore as createStore } from "redux";
import { userReducer } from "./user/userReducer.js";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'userReducer',
    storage: storage,
  };
  const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);
    const store = createStore(pReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

  const persistor = persistStore(store);

export  {persistor,store}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but createstore is deprecated in react 18 and also ReactDOM is deprecated for createstore we can use configureStore and for ReactDOM we can use createRoot

Comment: The Probléme for Provider i reloved it but i have a new probléme in reducer it show me an error Uncaught Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers